# .htaccess lowercase rewrite is not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mamp-pro

Very new to Apache here and htaccess rules. Please assume I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here. This is currently trying to be achieved currently on MAMP pro.

I'm trying to force all URL's to redirect to a lowercase version if the URL has any uppercase letters in it.

The solutions I'm finding are not reaping any results. `.htaccess` markup is as follows:

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# PROBLEM HERE: apparently this works
CheckSpelling on
CheckCaseOnly on
# END PROBLEM

# 301 redirect with trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And when it comes to adding this to the `httpd.conf`:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

the server then does nothing. I've attempted wrapping it in `<Directory>` and `<Virtualhost>` but to no avail.

Comment: Well in the case where “it errors”, you go “check log” first of all …

Comment: Updated to include error

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap says it should be within the server config or the virtualhost config. Also, my gut feeling says that the internal router of Wordpress may be causing you issues too

Comment: When I add it to the MAMP httpd conf, it doesn't change anything when not wrapped, or wrapped in `<Virtualhost>` or `<Directory>`

Comment: Wordpress has an internal router. It matches the url according to some url structure you have set up. Even if this RewriteMap did work as expected, you may end up with an url that Wordpress does not recognise, or an url that Wordpress will rewrite to a known url based on some algorithm. My best guess is that you did not restart Apache after changing your config, but I would recommend to change your `301` to `302` redirects to avoid sticky redirects when testing your code. Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve with this redirect?

Comment: Hiya. That's probably the one thing I have done right :) I've restarted Apache each time after changing the httpd.conf

Comment: For what I want to achieve, please see question. Apart from what it says I'm not sure what you are asking to be elaborated.